# How to make slideshow last long before moving onto next slide and how to move dots up to the top left of the slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got two questions:

1. How do i make the slideshow last longer, before moving onto the next one, because at the moment it is only lasting about 1 second. I have messed around with the following line

setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

But all that does is set it to some sort of delay moving from slide to slide. Where as I want it, so it stay on slide number 1, them waits about 10 seconds ore so and then move onto slide number 2.

2. How do i move the indicating dots to the top left of the slideshow as I change the margin to a negative number, but that just messed the dots completely.

As stated above IO have change the following line:

setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

and change the margins, but nothing.

The following code is for both Q1 & 2.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: laft;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  float: left;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
My HTML Is:

<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the slideshow with an indication of where I wish the dots to be.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/324BY.jpg

Any help appreciated and thank you in advance

Comment: Still looking for assistance on moving the dots on top of the slideshow :/

Answer (score 0):

Changing your timeout to 10 seems to stay on one slide for 10 seconds.  setTimeout(showSlides, 10000);

I know you had said you previously tried this though.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 10000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: laft;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  float: left;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: 2000 to 10000 stays on the same slide for about 2 seconds and then gives me a white space/slide for 10 seconds :/

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

Change the below to "Wait" before triggering the next image

> setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Change fade animation levels if you want the transition between images to have some delay

> -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

and

> animation-duration: 2s;

**Question 2:**

Simply move your dots div before the container div

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: laft;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 150px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  float: left;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
My HTML Is:
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.mediawiki.org/static/images/project-logos/mediawikiwiki.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.mediawiki.org/static/images/project-logos/mediawikiwiki.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.mediawiki.org/static/images/project-logos/mediawikiwiki.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @takrishnna 2000 to 5000 stays on the same slide for about 2 seconds and then gives me a white space/slide for 5 seconds :/

Comment: Also the dots have moved to the top of the slideshow, but when i try to put them on the slideshow, then i end up with big white spaces between them

Comment: are you able to see view by "run code snippet" - it displays the image for 5 seconds before fade animation kicks in

Comment: you asked this "How do i move the indicating dots to the top left of the slideshow as I change the margin to a negative number, but that just messed the dots completely." - the dots are top left of the slide show ?? - I don't understand your new comments

Comment: I want the dot to the top left of the slideshow, but on the slideshow, I posted this pic https://imgur.com/EiC4vSu of where i wish to dots to be as i indicated this with a black square :/

Comment: And with the slideshow duration, then i receive this for https://imgur.com/TzHVFJU 5 seconds

Comment: @takrishma I managed to get the timer fixed, but the i am still having trouble with the dots.